# How to tighten gates belt drive on Focus planet 8

Tags: belt-drive

the belt on my focus planet 8 is becoming a bit loose and I thought of tightening it.

The rear wheel setup on the focus is similar to the one in the video from bikefriday below:

What is different is that my bike does not have the adjuster holes to change the tension. There is the big long thread, but at the end there is no hole for an allan key nor is there a hole for a screwdriver to adjust?

Pictures below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Below are the pictures from the side:
[sideview1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyr55.jpg)
[image: sideview2]

I imagined that the process should be: open the 2 bolts from the outside, then tighten the inside "bolt" on the chainstay. however I don't see a way how to perform the last step, as it is not a bolt nor a screw that i have on the inside chainstay.

thanks

Comment: I think a picture will vastly improve the chances of getting a useful answer - please upload one.

Comment: Did you receive a manual with the bike? That would tell you how to adjust belt tension.

Comment: Unfortunately no manual with the bike. Also I checked the website of derby cycles, and the manual they have is very generic and doesn't explain :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your pictures, one from the side would be nice.  I did a search and came up with the following picture.

[image: Focus Planet 8]

If this is what your bike looks like, then you need to loosen the two bolts I've labeled on both sides (4 total) and slide the wheel back until the belt is tensioned correctly. Make sure the wheel is straight and even on both sides when tightening everything back up. From looking at your pictures, it also looks like you should tighten the bolt on the inside of the chainstay where you've circled in red to prevent the wheel from slipping.

Comment: Hi Kibbee,the picture you posted is exactly how it looks on my bike. The loosening the green labeled bolts should be doable. But I don't know how to tighten the bolt on the inside of the chainstay (circled in red). There is no bolt/screw. Just the long thread. I will take a pic from the side and upload.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not really familiar with this type of setup so maybe somebody else can chime in once we have some better pictures. If there's no head on the front facing side, then there must be a bolt head on the other side, although it's not quite clear how one would access that.

Comment: It looks like you tighten the tension bolt with an allen key. If you look at your (the OP's) photo carefully, you can see it takes a small allen wrench (aka hex key, hex wrench).

Comment: ok cool, let me try with a small allen.

Comment: Thanks RoboKaren, you were right. I initially thought allen key would not fit. But it turns out that it was just gunked up with mud. After cleaning, allen key fitted. If you post your answer as "answer" instead of comment i will gladly accept it.